# PyQt -- Create a menuBar outside of MainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt

I am working with PyQt4 and I am trying to create a menubar in an window that is not MainWindow. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QMenuBar actually just a typical widget. You can specify any object as a parent.

As for C++ this code works fine:

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QMenuBar>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    QMenuBar *mb = new QMenuBar(this);
    mb->addAction("Hello");
}

Widget::~Widget()
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed. I assumed that all windows acted the same way that the mainWindow does, which was rather silly of me.